# How to reinstall Django

Tags: django

For some reasons I removed Django
first I entered

```
>> import django
>> django.__path__
```

and then I entered

```
sudo  rm -r path
```

in terminal.
And now when I'm trying to reinstall it I enter these commands

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python3-django
```

i see

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   python3-django is already the newest version (1:1.11.11-1ubuntu1.8).
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.

And then I enter

```
django-admin --version
```

i see

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin", line 5, in 
>       from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

What should I do to reinstall it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install Django using this command:

```
pip3 install Django
```

Comment: i did it now and when i enter django-admin --version i see 3.0.5, but when i enter"python manage.py runserver " i see this error : "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'"

Comment: I'm on mac so it's maybe different but I have to write python3 manage.py runserver

Answer (score 0):

Like how we have `pip install <filename>` to install a package.

Similarly, to uninstall a package, you can do `pip uninstall <filename>`

in your case,
to install Django : `pip install django`
to Uninstall Django : `pip uninstall django`